# PHP filesize for files in directory not shown

Tags: php, foreach, glob, filesize

I would like to display the filesize for every file in a directory in a table.
But the size of the files can´t be shown.

This is the code I use:

```
$dir    = 'audio';

$files = array_slice(scandir('audio'), 2);
sort($files, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);

$size = (glob("audio/*.mp3"));
        
echo "<table border><tr><th>Dateiname</th><th>Dateingröße</th></tr>";
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        echo 
        "<tr>
            <td>
                <a href='audio/" . $file . "'target='_blank'>" . $file . "</a>
            </td>
            <td>" . filesize($size) . " Byte
            </td>
        </tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this, so the size is shown in the second table column?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `filesize($file)`?

Comment: `$size` is array, there is no `filesize` value.

Comment: @NigelRen, that won't work, because `filesize()` needs a full path to the file residing in the `audio` directory that was scanned.

Comment: Please be more specific than "can't be shown" about why this fails. Do you get an error? What is it? Do you get an unexpected result instead? What is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be a bit confused about what each function actually does and returns.

Here is a working version of the code, I removed some parts as they were kind of doing the same thing. And while you were looping through an array `$files`, you were using another array `$size` inside your loop within a function that accepts only a string `filesize()`.

```
<?php

$files = (glob("audio/*.mp3"));
sort($files, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);

echo "<table border><tr><th>Dateiname</th><th>Dateingröße</th></tr>";
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo
        "<tr>
            <td>
                <a href='".$file."'target='_blank'>".basename($file)."</a>
            </td>
            <td>".filesize($file)." Byte
            </td>
        </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs will tell you that [glob()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) returns an `array`, while [filesize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) wants a `string`, and more precisely, the name of the file to perform the `stat()` call on.

You're looping over the list of files from a relative directory ('audio'), while `scandir()` will give back *filenames only*. To get the file size of every file returned by `scandir()`, you have to pass the (relative) path to the file. That is, including its parent directory.

Change this:

`filesize($size)`

To this:

`filesize("audio/$file")`

And it should work (untested).